# generate dynamic secret name inside kubernetes deployment file

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-secrets

I have 2 secrets i.e. production and staging. I want to dynamically load this secret in deployment file using the environment variable being set in same file

```
env:
          - name: NODE_ENV
            value: "production"


 - name: general-secret
          secret:
            secretName: general-production-secret
```

I want to load environment specific secrets like using

```
        secretName: general-{{env. NODE_ENV}}-secret
```

Is it possible?

Comment: I think this will replay your question https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/52787. Anyway, you could use software like kustomize (https://kustomize.io/) to manage yaml files.

Comment: I need to do it from inside of deployment file.

Comment: As far as I know there is not way to do that without using something external like `kubectl kustomize`.Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, this is not possible unless you have [Helm](https://helm.sh/) chart for your applications, then you can make this possible

this is a solution in helm chart close to what you need 
[Dynamically accessing values depending on variable values in a Helm chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52742241/dynamically-accessing-values-depending-on-variable-values-in-a-helm-chart)

Comment: This is correct statement. It's not possible to refer to variables on a Kubernetes Manifest. This is nos supported and that's why we have solutions like Helm and Kustomize. They exist to fill a gap and let us create manifests programmatically.