# custom kubernetes scripts as template

Tags: kubernetes

I have a kubernetes deployment script as a template for project deployment. But I have different project for this script and each project need a new namespace and annotation and environment variable.

Now I create properties file for each project and write a shell script that when I deploy the project, the properties of this project will replace the variable in the template and then deploy this deployment scriplt. As below

```
minReplicas: ${HYBRIS_MIN_REPLICA}
maxReplicas: ${HYBRIS_MAX_REPLICA}

hybris.scaler.replica.max=3
hybris.scaler.replica.min=2
```

Do we have any good ways to implement such things for custom the kubernetes script as a template

Comment: have you tried using [helm](https://helm.sh/docs/intro/quickstart/)?

Comment: You can try kustomize. It is baked into kubectl.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61482060/generate-dynamic-secret-name-inside-kubernetes-deployment-file/61489962#61489962

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Helm](https://helm.sh/) it is a package manger for kubernetes which give you the ability to have templates for your deployment or whatever scripts or config for kubernetes.
and you can have different values for some variables in your deployment script.
you can read about [Values](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/values_files/) file and [control flows](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/control_structures/) which written in a _helper scripts with the following format:

```
{{ if PIPELINE }}
# Do something
{{ else if OTHER PIPELINE }}
# Do something else
{{ else }}
# Default case
{{ end }}
```

**Values.yaml**

```
hybris:
  scaler:
    replica:
      max: 3
      min: 2
```

**delpoyment.yaml**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata: name
  labels: test
spec:
   replicas: {{ .Values.hybris.scaler.replica.min }}
```

This will help if you read about it.