# Helm function to set value based on a variable?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I'm learning Helm to setup my 3 AWS EKS clusters - sandbox, staging, and production.

How can I set up my templates so some values are derived based on which cluster the chart is being installed at? For example, in my `myapp/templates/deployment.yaml` I may want

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  ...
spec:
  {{- if not .Values.autoscaling.enabled }}
  replicas: {{ .Values.replicaCount }}
  {{- end }}
```

I may want `replicas` to be either `1`, `2`, or `4` depending if I'm installing the chart in my `sandbox`, `staging`, or `production` cluster respectively? I wanna do same trick for cpu and memory requests and limits for my pods for example.

I was thinking of having something like this in my `values.yaml` file

```
environments:
  - sandbox
  - staging
  - production
perClusterValues:
  replicas:
    - 1
    - 2
    - 4
  cpu:
    requests:
      - 256m
      - 512m
      - 1024m
    limits:
      - 512m
      - 1024m
      - 2048m
  memory:
    requests:
      - 1024Mi
      - 1024Mi
      - 2048Mi
    limits:
      - 2048Mi
      - 2048Mi
      - 3072Mi
```

So if I install a helm chart in the `sandbox` environment, I want to be able to do

```
$ helm install myapp myapp --set environment=sandbox

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  ...
spec:
  {{- if not .Values.autoscaling.enabled }}
  # In pseudo-code, in my YAML files
  # Get the index value from .Values.environments list
  # based on pass-in environment parameter
  {{ $myIndex = indexOf .Values.environments .Value.environment }}
  replicas: {{ .Values.perClusterValues.replicas $myIndex }}
  {{- end }}
```

I hope you understand my logic, but what is the correct syntax? Or is this even a good approach?

Comment: Have you looked at https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/control_structures/?

Comment: Looking at https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#lists-and-list-functions, there is no built-in helm function for getting the index of an element in a list. However, you can just use a dictionary instead.

Comment: LOL @ShaneBishop I was just looking at that page. When you say dictionary, I'll have to define it, for example, `relicas: sandbox: 1, staging: 2, production: 4` ?

Comment: I'm not sure if you can define a dictionary directly in your `values.yml`. However, the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53598486/8593689) seems to do something similar to what you want to do.

Comment: @ShaneBishop see my own answer to my post here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66197850/in-my-helm-template-why-is-pluck-evaluating-to-a-float64

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `helm install -f` option to pass an extra YAML values file in, and this takes precedence over the chart's own `values.yaml` file.  So using exactly the template structure you already have, you can provide alternate values files

```yaml
# sandbox.yaml
autoscaling:
  enabled: false
replicaCount: 1
```

```yaml
# production.yaml
autoscaling:
  enabled: true
replicaCount: 5
```

And then when you go to deploy the chart, run it with

```sh
helm install myapp . -f production.yaml
```

(You can also `helm install --set replicaCount=3` to override specific values, but the `--set` syntax is finicky and unusual; using a separate YAML file per environment is probably easier.  Some tooling might be able to take advantage of JSON files also being valid YAML to write out additional deploy-time customizations.)

Comment: I thought about this solution, but I'm shying away from maintaining 3 separate files. I also want to shy away from passing the value on the command line, since I'll have a LOT of these key/value pairs the will need to be set based on the environment/cluster.