# In my Helm template, why is pluck evaluating to a float64?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

As a followup question to my post [Helm function to set value based on a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66191604/helm-function-to-set-value-based-on-a-variable), and modifying the answer given in [Dynamically accessing values depending on variable values in a Helm chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52742241/dynamically-accessing-values-depending-on-variable-values-in-a-helm-chart), I'm trying this

```
$ helm version --short
v3.5.2+g167aac7

values.yaml
-----------
env: sandbox
environments:
  sandbox: 0
  staging: 1
  production: 2
replicaCount:
  - 1
  - 2
  - 4

templates/deployments.yaml
--------------------------
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
...
spec:
  {{- if not .Values.autoscaling.enabled }}
  replicas: {{ index .Values.replicaCount (pluck .Values.env .Values.environments | first | default .Values.environments.sandbox) }}
```

But I get

```
$ helm template . --dry-run
Error: template: guestbook/templates/deployment.yaml:10:15: executing "guestbook/templates/deployment.yaml" at <index .Values.replicaCount (pluck .Values.env .Values.environments | first | default .Values.environments.sandbox)>: error calling index: cannot index slice/array with type float64
```

Why is `pluck` returning a `float64` instead of an integer, which I expect since my `environments` dictionary values are integers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I do this, that is, pipe `pluck` with the `int` converter, it works, but it doesn't explain why `pluck` returns a `float64` value.

```
templates/deployments.yaml
--------------------------
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
...
spec:
  {{- if not .Values.autoscaling.enabled }}
  replicas: {{ index .Values.replicaCount ((pluck .Values.env .Values.environments | first | default .Values.environments.sandbox) | int) }}
```

**UPDATE:** It turns out to be a known bug. See https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/yaml/issues/45

Comment: You are missing a close parentheses.  Are you showing all the code that produces the result?

Comment: @erk I copy/pasted code that actually ran for me. i don't see the missing `()`. I see 2 opening `(` and 2 closing `)`? The inner `()` for the `pluck` command itself, and the outer `()` to pipe the whole `(pluck)` command with `int`? So it's `{{ index .Values.replicaCount ((pluck ...) | int) }}`?