# How to pass a deployment's full name to a variable in helm values.yaml?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

How to pass the `fullname` of a dependant chart into another chart in the `values.yaml`?

My `values.yaml` looks like this:

```
##
## Prisma chart configuration
##
prisma:
  enabled: true
  image:
    pullPolicy: Always
  auth:
    enabled: true
    secret: scret
  database:
    host: {{ template "postgresql.fullname" . }}
    port: 5432
    password: dbpass


##
## Postgreqsl chart configuration
##
postgresql:
  enabled: true
  imagePullPolicy: Always
  postgresqlUsername: prisma
  postgresqlPassword: dbpass
  persistence:
    enabled: true
    storageClass: storage-0
```

In there, I need to pass the name of the `postgresql` instance to `prisma`.

If I try to install this, it gives me the following error:

```
error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: invalid map key: map[interface {}]interface {}{"template \"postgresql.fullname\" .":interface {}(nil)}
```

Comment: take a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/51197457/7568391

Answer (score 1):

If your charts looking as:

```
charts
--- prisma
----- templates
------- prisma.yaml
----- values.yaml
--- postgresql
----- templates
------- postgresql.yaml
----- values.yaml
requirements.yaml
values.yaml
```

in prisma values.yaml define:

```
dbhost: defaultdbhost
```

Then you can define in global values.yaml:

```
prisma:
  dbhost: mydbhost
```

And into prisma.yaml use:

```
prisma:
  enabled: true
  image:
    pullPolicy: Always
  auth:
    enabled: true
    secret: scret
  database:
    host: {{ .Values.dbhost }}
    port: 5432
    password: dbpass
```

For understand overriding values [read this document](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/master/docs/chart_template_guide/subcharts_and_globals.md)